# Where do I find Alchemy Orbs and Fire Crystals?

Tags: spiral-knights

I'm finding plenty of Eternal Orbs of alchemy and Radiant Fire Crystals in FSC, which is great for upgrading 4* gear to 5*, but I'm running out of 4* gear to upgrade. Where do I find the other orbs and crystals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've only tested on elite mode, but I hear difficulty doesn't affect *what* drops, just *how much*. So far:

**Alchemy:**

- 5* - Eternal - Strata 5&6
- 4* - Elite - Strata 4&5
- 3* - Advanced - Stratum 3&4
- 2* - Simple - Stratum 2&3
- 1* - Flawed - Stratum 1&2

**Forging:**

- 5* - Radiant - Stratum 6
- 4* - Shining - Stratum 5
- 3* - Glowing - Stratum 4
- 2* - Warm - ???
- 1* - Dim - ???
- 0* - Cracked - ???

Comment: Eternal drops at rotting metropolis on elite if you have a elemental brandish take it there and start mining. Elite orbs drop on Stratum 4 boss levels on elite mode. Advanced drop in the stratum 3 missons on elite, simple drops on snarbly on elite, flawed drops on pet missions on elite.

Comment: @user53961 I've had alchemy orbs drop on all difficulty modes, and also outside of boss levels. Rarity drops don't depend on the type of weapon you're using, or even the specific levels you're playing in. They depend on Stratum (for alchemy orbs and fire crystals) and RNG.

Answer (score 0):

In Cold Blood is a great place to get 4* shining fire crystals. It gives around 30 per run on elite if you're lucky. The least I got was 10. If you're good at rushing then you can get it done in less than 5 minutes.

In Cold Blood has the most amount of prize boxes in the whole game. You can also get both eternals and elite orbs there as it's right in between, but eternal orb rate drop is more than elite.